# Programmatically restarting IIS Hosted WCF service - change Bindings issue

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, wcf-binding

I got into this not very good situation.. When web application starts - I set up different routes for my services so tenants of my multi-user app connect to:

```
private static void RegisterRoutes()
{
   // Setup URL's for each customer
   using (var cmc = new CoreModelContext())
   {
      foreach (var account in cmc.Accounts.Where(aa => aa.IsActive).ToList())
      {
         RouteTable.Routes.Add(
              new ServiceRoute(account.AccountId + "/mobile", 
                               new MyServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MobileService)));
      }
   }
}
```

So, when my site/service starts - it grabs all accounts from the database and sets up the routes.

This is a single point of failure right there. Sometimes servers rebooted in wrong order and if SQL Server not started - this service starts in "weird" mode.

Today web service stopped responding. I checked logs - IIS recycled pool as scheduled (default settings) and started different worked process. Something didn't click and boom - server stopped responding. Routes wasn't registered...

So. My question is.. How to fix it best way? I can put routes to config file, but that will mean I have to maintain those id's in 2 places. Probably not that bad but I'd rather do it differently if possible.

Is it possible to to programmatically try and restart pool? What happens when exception thrown in `Application_Start` ? Right now I'm not trapping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is a "fix" but when we've got similar dependency issues, we make sure the other dependencies cannot successfully start in "weird" mode. In this case, I would bring the app down hard if the sql server isn't avaliable, at least in production. Far better to have nothing being processed than have things being processed wrong.

Comment: I agree with you 100%. Luckily nothing being processed wrong in my case. So, how would I bring it down "hard"? Ideally I'd like to fail app-start in such a way that IIS keep's trying and when connection to SQL finally establishes it would pick it up

Comment: I would just throw an exception when I can't start because I can't see SQL. My understanding is that unhandled exceptions should kill the app pool and keep it from starting. Another option that just hit me would be an offline monitoring process of some sort.

Comment: Right now I'm not trapping errors and obviously that doesn't work :( Offline monitoring is not needed since customers email me 5 minutes after it's down :-) I just don't like to get those emails at most inappropriate times